# Flask/HTML: Using a button to display confirmation message, then redirect

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, confirm

New to Flask, I have implemented buttons to redirect onclick but I am having trouble with a button to redirect AFTER a confirmation message. In my HTML I have:

`<button type="button" name="deleteall" value=False onclick="window.confirm('Are you sure you want to clear all entries?')">Delete All</button>`

The confirmation window appears as intended but I need to use the deleteall variable to redirect to my `@app.route('/deleteall')` in my app.py, else if the user cancels on the confirmation, do nothing.

Do I even need to use name/value in the button tag? Is there a different way to achieve this?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: hi, interesting, I think you could also use a hidden input field

Comment: hi @IronMan, can you expand on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some javascript

```js
function doThing(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.confirm('Do you want to do?') ? 
    window.location.href = '/deleteall' :
    null;
};
```

```html
<button type="button" name="deleteall" value=False onclick="doThing(event)">Delete All</button>
```

Comment: Yes this will work, was trying to avoid javascript but I'll bite the bullet. Thanks!